# Android: open camera and get raw data in C level

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, android-camera

I want to open android tablet's camera and get the data from camera in C level. After that I will modify the data, and C level will be efficient.

Now I'm thinking using the V4L2 C code. But I find the open function of V4L2 need the parameter of the camera's name, such as '/dev/video0'. However I can't find something like that in my tablet's dev folder. Besides, I am not sure whether using the V4L2 will be the right solution.

Does anyone know anything about this?

Comment: What version of Android?  Android 4.4 provides the new ImageReader class (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageReader.html), which speeds access to YUV buffers from the camera.

Comment: Thank you. Any version would be fine. But I need to get them in C level so I will modify the data in C level directly, which is more efficient than Java.

Answer (score 1):

on my device "OpenCV for Android" does not provide required performance neither in 'native' mode nor in 'java' mode. it gives FPS=2 in 1920x1080, in same time when java MediaRecorder can record 1920x1080 with FPS=15

I'm trying to solve it using the code from Android Open Source Project used by native Camera application:

```
static void android_hardware_Camera_native_setup(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz,
    jobject weak_this, jint cameraId)
{
    sp<Camera> camera = Camera::connect(cameraId);

    if (camera == NULL) {
        jniThrowRuntimeException(env, "Fail to connect to camera service");
        return;
    }

    // make sure camera hardware is alive
    if (camera->getStatus() != NO_ERROR) {
        jniThrowRuntimeException(env, "Camera initialization failed");
        return;
    }

    jclass clazz = env->GetObjectClass(thiz);
    if (clazz == NULL) {
        jniThrowRuntimeException(env, "Can't find android/hardware/Camera");
        return;
    }

    // We use a weak reference so the Camera object can be garbage collected.
    // The reference is only used as a proxy for callbacks.
    sp<JNICameraContext> context = new JNICameraContext(env, weak_this, clazz, camera);
    context->incStrong(thiz);
    camera->setListener(context);

    // save context in opaque field
    env->SetIntField(thiz, fields.context, (int)context.get());
}
```

Comment: If you are good in ndk code for image processing ,help me to complete the ndk snippit of the receiver end from the below attached pdf. https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiW85vpjMjPAhUJtI8KHfLODxEQFgggMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.researchgate.net%2Ffile.PostFileLoader.html%3Fid%3D5759370596b7e49f4d75ff68%26assetKey%3DAS%253A370999498428416%25401465464581089&usg=AFQjCNH7UNcLYC2ltfOtOcC4e4X1IuACOg&sig2=TJ1j1ZvlZqLZcarImnqHYg

Answer (score 0):

You can always build a JNI method for the Java classes to get access from C. Another way could be using OpenCV for Android: [OpenCV4Android](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html)

This gives you a interface to the camera, but as far as I remember, there is currently no support for Android 4.3+.